Brake disks corrosion around the contours of the brake pads after the car was stationary for 2 months outside
I left my Mercedes W210 outside for 2 months without driving it (only driven it once per month). It had been raining. There is a corrosion around the place where the brake pads had contact with the disk. When I touch it, these lines are a bit higher than the rest of the surface. Now when I break I hear a wobbly sound and a slight vibration in the pedal. Will this go away? My mechanic told me that it would go away in time, but how much? I've driven 300 km so far.
So

Will this go away if I keep driving and how much more should I drive?
How to prevent it? I have two cars and they are in two cities and either one should be left outside for prolonged periods of time

I just installed these new brake pads and disks 6 months ago and have driven less than 1000km with them.


Assuming no defects, it should go away. Sooner with heavy use of the brake (driving down a mountain road does wonders), later with gentle city driving.
Sorry, the only way to prevent this is to

keep the unused car dry
or regular use of both cars

